# How do I stop my recyclerview from resetting?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, linearlayoutmanager

I'm developing a chat UI. When I send a message, it inflates correctly. However, when I send another message, the new message is added at the top of a new screen, instead of below the previous message. 
In addition, when I receive a reply, it added below the one I sent. After this, the next message received or sent will be added on a new screen. How do I stop this from happening?

Here's my layout.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="8dp">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/message_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/textbox"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/textbox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/txtMessage"
            android:hint="Enter message"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="6"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSend"
            android:text="SEND"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_width="64dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding a new message to the adapter:

```
String messageString = txtMessage.getText().toString();
        if (messageString.trim().length() > 0) {
            // update the views
            txtMessage.setText("");
            Message message = new Message(messageString);
            message.setDirection(Message.OUTGOING_MESSAGE);
            adapter.addMessage(message);
```

The Chat adapter class:

```
class ChatAdapter
            extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

        Context context;
        private final List<Message> messages;

        ChatAdapter(Context context, List<Message> messages) {
            this.context = context;
            this.messages = messages;

        }

        public void addMessage(Message message) {
            messages.add(message);
            Log.i("MESSAGE", message.getText());
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `adapter.notfifyItemInserted` instead of `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged`

Answer (score 0):

1) make sur you used this command :

```
linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
```

2) I don't see your `onBindViewHolder` method in the ChatAdapter class, you should use that, it will definitely solve your problem

3) When you add a message, do it like this :

```
String messageString = txtMessage.getText().toString();
    if (messageString.trim().length() > 0) {
        // update the views
        txtMessage.setText("");
        Message message = new Message(messageString);
        ListOfMessage.add(message);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```